# Where can I find code examples of different variations of Perlin noise?

Tags: procedural-generation

I have seen the PCG wiki, and it is a great resource. But a lot of the articles are very brief and it is hard to find good links on specific things.

I have been searching for ways to transform my Perlin noise height maps to make ridges, rivers, and other terrain features. I also can't find any articles on how to divide up the map into different areas for calculating texture coordinates or other values specific to the game. I have only been able to find websites detailing their software that can generate the different things, but no code or explanations. Are there any good sources of code examples/explanations on how to do the above mentioned with Perlin noise?

PS. This should probably be a community wiki. I don't know how to make it as one though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[World Generation Breakdown](http://www.nolithius.com/game-development/world-generation-breakdown)
[Perlin Noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm)
[advanced perlin noise](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/morenoise/morenoise.htm)
[NVidia GPU Gems 2. Chapter 26. Implementing Improved Perlin Noise](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter26.html)
[NVidia GPU Gems 3. Chapter 1. Generating Complex Procedural Terrains Using the GPU](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html)

Also 2 articles (in Russian) with source code:

http://blog.wonderville.ru/procedural-perlin-noise/
http://blog.wonderville.ru/perlin-noise-simplex-noise/

Comment: Here is an English version of the Russian simplex noise page: http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:363xWad34LMJ:www.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf+simplex+noise&hl=en&gl=ca&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESibkqdImxpGw0Ln7jDyRTX3qYbtmpNvkSKP0BQtB1yI5aMMrzymlkpdgEuYgDC-fQHDTD4gzpGcATNE8G8aUtyhNcPROEGhMHiMPbzjDrSfmyYi361dA88_cFmQpGEWesOH9_2_&sig=AHIEtbRH9baL0f_KDPAtREBaD4q7r7WSdw the original pdf can be downloaded here: http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Most pages claiming to cover perlin noise actually cover something else. If you want the real deal, read [Improved Noise reference implementation](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/) by Ken Perlin himself. There you will also find a link to the [SIGGRAPH 2002 paper](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/paper445.pdf) describing the algorithm in detail.